# Why Database backup size differs when backing up from Query and SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am confused with the size of the file I backup with SSMS and Query.
If I create a file from SSMS in its default folder something like "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.NAMEDINSTANCE\MSSQL\Backup" the outfile say Db1.bak is about **198292 KB**
Same database if I backup with the query `"backup database Db1 to disk='D:\Db1.bak'` the file size is just **6256 KB**

Sometimes the other database say Db2 gives the same filesize i.e **6256 KB**(Both Db1 and Db2 have identical(same) schemas just data in it are different.)
And backup with SSMS gives **33608 KB** which seems satisfactory.

I also tried verifying all database in SSMS like this `RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\BACKUP\Db1.bak'
GO` and result gives valid in every database check.

I also tried deleting Db1 from SSMS and restoring the less KB file and checked some data of few tables (Not All) and it seems showing all data in tables properly but the filesize dissatisfies me.

Thank You.

Comment: if i am not wrong the query will take a compressed backup.

Comment: SSMS, when using the GUI, still runs a set of SQL Statements. Script out the query SSMS is running and post that too (however, the answer may suddenly be apparently before you do that :) ).

Comment: @Srikarmogaliraju I didn't know that. But it compress to a same filesize like Db1 and Db2 are same??

Comment: Only if that's the default setting @Srikarmogaliraju.

Comment: @Larnu I ain't understood your comment.

Comment: Another thing that could show different sizes between folders is NTFS compression which most likely is not enabled for the SQL Server backup folder but could be for D:\ (if SQL Server backup compression is not a part of the picture).

Comment: @squillman Can I turn on/off data compression when creating backup through query?

Comment: What don't you understand @RitaShroff ?

Comment: @Larnu This : Script out the query SSMS is running and post that too (however, the answer may suddenly be apparently before you do that :) ) --- what this mean script out the query SSMS????

Comment: Well you said that you're creating the backup in SSMS, so (*I assume*) you're using the GUI. The GUI still executes a query, so we need to know the *other* query you're executing. One is `ackup database Db1 to disk='D:\Db1.bak'`, and the other is "?". In the GUI get the script by using the appropriately named "script" button and include it in your question#.

Comment: @Larnu I create 1 backup with Query i.e `backup database Db1 to disk='D:\Db1.bak` -- I run this query from vb.net code using sqlcommand and other backup using GUI in ssms like - Right Click on Db1->Tasks->Backup..

Comment: Yes, @RitaShroff and what is they query you're (effectively) running in SSMS...?

Comment: @Larnu `backup database Db1 to disk='D:\Db1.bak` in ssms/vb.net code and other via SSMS GUI (no query)

Comment: Using the GUI (in SSMS) **does** run a query... As I stated above. What is that query? (Have a read of my comments again and add the query to your question please). Without the query you're running in SSMS we can only but guess; and questions about "why this code isn't working" without said code are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh okay, I know today that there is script while backup.. Sorry.  This is query when I backup via SSMS using GUI `BACKUP DATABASE [Db1] TO  DISK = N'D:\BACKUP\Db1.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Db1-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO`

Comment: @Larnu So is it safe using `backup database Db1 to disk='D:\Db1.bak` **over** `BACKUP DATABASE [Db1] TO DISK = N'D:\BACKUP\Db1.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'Db1-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10 GO`

Comment: That depends if the "simpler" statement meets the requirements of your backups, Rita Shroff. For a "simple" full back up, yes, that'll provide you with all you need. I suspect that,like initially mentioned, you have compression on my default, and using the GUI, with the settings is not making use of that (and that if you selected to Compress in the GUI, you'd get a similar size).

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect that,like initially mentioned, you have **compression** on my
>   default, and using the GUI, with the settings is not making use of
>   that (and that if you selected to Compress in the GUI, you'd get a
>   similar size)

If the server option `backup compression default` is `on`, even if you don't mention it in your `backup` command, `compression` will be applied. So in both cases there would be `compressed backup`. But it's easy to see, just run this command for both `backups`:

```
restore headeronly
from disk = 'here_the_full_path_with_filename';
```

In the 5th column you'll get the flag if your `backup` is `compressed`.

But the cause of this difference is another one, and you'll see it when run `restore headeronly`: you made **multiple** `backups` to the same file.

You used `backup` command `with noinit` from `SSMS`, and the same `file name`, so now this file contains more than one `backup`, and `restore headeronly` will show them all.